# A green vertical line on my laptop screen

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-repair

I get a green vertical line on the screen of my laptop, and i think it's because the pressure or something, is there any solution for it ?

[image: The photo of my screen]

Comment: Where is it at? This looks like a screenshot so we can't see it.

Comment: If it doesn't appear in a screenshot, then the issue is physical. Take a photo of the screen & post that.

Comment: Looking at the full-size image link, there's a bright line on the right edge, but it doesn't include the system tray at the top.  If that's what you're referring to, it would not be a hardware issue (that wouldn't exclude the system tray).  That line is being rendered as part of the screen image, so it's a software issue.

Comment: @fixer1234 that's the scrollbar for the terminal window. The size of the orange line will shrink once more data is populated in the terminal.

Comment: i changed the picture

Comment: Your screen is broken. Physically broken. The crack or damaged portion is likely behind the frame on the edge of the screen. The only solution is to replace the screen.

Comment: In addition to the vertical line, it looks like there's damage on the right side.  So yeah, the fix would be replacing the screen.  That won't be cheap.  If the laptop is many years old (say more than about 5 yrs), compare the price of the repair to the cost of a new laptop.  You'll probably get a 90 day warranty on the repair, and other components in the laptop will be approaching the end of their service lives, so the repair could be throwing good money after bad.  You might be better off putting it towards a new laptop.

Comment: Okey thank you very much all of you